# Converting dates from YY to YYYY --- how do compilers/interpreters know to use the correct century?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, date-conversion, 2-digit-year

I was just doing a bunch of importing of an old database, and as I was watching the results roll by, I wondered, how/why does it know to convert 12/31/13 to 12/31/2013, but 12/31/99 to 12/31/1999?  ("it" in this case is Python's strftime(%Y/%m/%d) function)

What happens in 2050?  Will a record for 12/31/50 be interpreted by default as 2050, 1950, or 2150?

I realize it may vary depending on language, and that there are probably flags/options to specifically force the use of a certain century.  But when you don't explicitly do so, what's making that judgment call by default?

Comment: Each language/database documents its date conversion rules.  The two character year format is no longer supported by the ISO date format.

Answer (score 2):

It varies by database, each has a default time span.

SQL Server's default time span is: `1950-2049`, so `50` becomes `1950`, but `49` becomes `2049`.

In MySQL and Oracle it's `1970-2069`

In Postgresql it's centered on `2020`, so whichever year is closest to 2020, which seems to also be `1970-2069`

All of the defaults span into the future and therefore custom criteria is frequently necessary.

Two digit years can be confused, take `2010-05-07` and change it to a 2-digit year, `10-05-07`? Nope, should be `05-07-10`, at least in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CAST('2010-05-07' AS DATE)  --  2010-05-07
      ,CAST('10-05-07' AS DATE)    --  2007-10-05
      ,CAST('05-07-10' AS DATE)    --  2010-05-07
```

Invalid dates make it easy to determine the supplied date format usually.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the compilier documentation.

And more important: **Don't use 2 digit year whenever possible**!

Comment: Another option is to try out a range of 2-digit years and see what 4-digit year your database assigns them to.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages/DBMSes got a default, but allow setting the century break to a custome value.

You should check documentation if/how this is possible.